# Custom sound notification on Google Calendar events

Tags: notifications, google-calendar, custom-sounds

I have many calendars on Google Calendar:

1. Hospital appointment (blue)
2. Birthday calendar (yellow)
3. Payday calendar
4. My career's calendar

They are separated by the colours to make it easy for identification, but **I would like to separate the notification sound to go with the colours**. Some more urgent like an alarm, some less aggravating but still just a buzz or something.

It's confusing that they all use the same tone, and although via some apps I can differentiate these between text, voicemail, and Facebook, etc, it's not quite ideal. I have been looking through all calendar apps I can find for this thing.

Answer (score 4):

Setting up distinct alarms for separate calendars within the Google Calendar app--or for separate events on any of those calendars--is not a feature provided in the Google Calendar app. If you wish to have that function and to continue using the Google Calendar app, you'll need a third-party add-in such as [Calendar Event Reminder](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder). (CER)  That one costs a couple of bucks but there may be other options, perhaps even "free" apps.

Comment: it seems silly that a simple feature like this isn't part of the Google calendar app... or even just the ability to turn off notification sounds on a per calendar basis!

Answer (score 0):

The third-party app [Business Calendar 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal) includes the functionality you seek.

Specifically, it allows the user to specify different notification sounds for different calendars, or no notification sounds for specific calendars.

I'm sure Business Calendar 2 has this functionality, but you may be more interested in [aCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar), as it likely also has this functionality, but donates some of their revenue to a non-profit charitable organization.

Answer (score -2):

The feature you are looking for in the Google Calendar is already present.
You can find the instructions to do that at google support [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242)

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is just a link.  Second, by following the link you will see that it apparently is not possible to have more than one notification sound like the asker wants!

Comment: Indeed, the information presented in the link directly contradicts the assertion that this answer makes.